# How to combine duplicated rows based on unique values in a column and merge those values by |?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have the following data frame:

```
gene    gene_name   source  chromosome  details
1       a           A           2       01; xyz
1       a           A           2       02; ijk
2       b           B           3       03; efg
2       b           C           3       03; efg
3       c           D           4       04; lmn
3       c           D           4       05; opq
3       c           D           4       06; rst
4       NA          10          6       NA
4       NA          11          6       NA
```

I want to get the following output:

```
gene    gene_name   source  chromosome  details
1       a           A       2           01; xyz | 02;ijk
2       b           B, C    3           03; efg
3       c           D       4           04; lmn | 05; opq | 06; rst
4       NA          10, 11  6           NA | NA
```

I have tried to use `aggregate()` and `group_by()` in different ways, but did not get it.

Please guide.

Thanks.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5635580/sotos The posts you mentioned are not helpful. :-(

Comment: As per "Your post has been associated with similar questions. If these questions don’t resolve your question, ask a new one." I am going to re-post.

Comment: Link to new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958102/r-how-to-combine-duplicated-rows-from-multiple-columns-based-on-unique-values-i